# How to make https work at nodejs and vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I have a site written in Laravel and Vue.js, nodejs is also used. When I try to enter the site using the http protocol, everything is fine, when I try to enter the https protocol, half of the site does not load and in the console I get an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com:8443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NPIJFIo' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access- Control-Allow-Origin 'header is present on the requested resource.
```

Redirection to https is configured on nginx itself, but I cannot do it on nodejs. Also i can't understand, how to correct add ssl cert path to my app.js.

My app.js:

```
const app = require('express')(),
server = require('https').createServer(app),
Redis = require('redis'),
RedisClient = Redis.createClient(),
io = require('socket.io')(server),
cors = require('cors'),
axios = require('axios');


const myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
const domain = myArgs[0];
const SECRET_KEY = 'cZN^ZH8)mu~9e,>6M>3qKV=Ar^fFF,7/';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://example.com/api/bot/';

server.listen(8081);

app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}));
```

What am I doing wrong? I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue, and you need to add `cors` option for the socket.io server.

Refer to [Handling CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/) for Socket.io.

```
io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
});
```

Comment: change how you write, nothing changed :(

Comment: remove `cors` package usage and try.